# Link Stack Exchange account to GitHub instead of Google

Tags: support, user-accounts, linked-accounts

The title speaks for itself: I would unlink my Stack Exchange account from Google and attach it to my GitHub account instead.

Is that possible?

Comment: Did you mean to login? or in profile?

Comment: @SagarV I mean during login. I currently use the Connect with google button, but I  would like to use my github account instead for now on.